# View property returns 'undefined' when following a linkTo route

Tags: data-binding, ember.js, view

I have a custom view to display breadcrumbs for the current model navigation on a page, here's how it looks in my template (which is the singular model template):

```
<div class="breadcrumbs">
  {{view Mdm.BreadcrumbView}}
</div>
```

Here's what my view looks like to render out the breadcrumbs:

```
App.BreadcrumbView = Ember.View.extend
   templateName: 'breadcrumb'

   penultimate: (->
     content = @get('controller.content.self_and_ancestors')
     content[content.length - 2]
   ).property('controller.content')

   last: (->
     content = @get('controller.content.self_and_ancestors')
     content[content.length - 1]
   ).property('controller.content')
```

Here's the breadcrumb template that renders the data:

```
 <ul class="breadcrumb">
   {{#if view.penultimate}}
     <li>{{#linkTo group view.penultimate}}Back{{/linkTo}}</li>
   {{/if}}
   <li>{{view.last.name}}</li>
 </ul>
```

My model that the view is using (`controller.content`) has nested data `self_and_ancestors` that hold the breadcrumb data that I need for the current page I'm on.  I'm only interested in seeing the `last` object in that array and the one just before it to navigate one page back (that's what the `penultimate` and `last` are displaying).  The breadcrumbs render perfectly and I can navigate fine until I click the 'Back' (`penultimate`) link.  When I hit that I got the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

For some reason the content is undefined, but I'm not exactly sure why.  Any thoughts?

### Edit:

Welp, here's an example http://jsbin.com/ejazin/2.  It is, however, working in this example, which makes me thing something else may be the problem.  Basically every time you click a breadcrumb link in my app, the router does a `find` based on the ID which makes an ajax call to find the current group for that route and all sub groups.  Maybe the view is trying to pull out the `sub_groups` data before it's come back from the server...  Is there any way to check / prevent this?

### Edit Edit:

This might convey what I'm trying to do a bit more - http://jsbin.com/obazus/1/.

## Edit Edit Edit:

Ok, the issue is definitely the fact that the view is rendering and calling `penultimate` before the ajax request has finished in the model.  That being said - what's the best way to make sure it renders *after* the ajax request for the model is finished?

Comment: can you put an example in a jsbin, it will be easier to help out...

Comment: Yep, I'll shoot an example up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking more closely at your use case, what might help is to check out the new **router facelift** [here](https://gist.github.com/machty/5723945). It's still not wildly documented and should soon appear on the ember website as a blog post, but it's already merged into ember-latest so you will have access to the new implementation. Especially the `beforeModel` & `afterModel` hook's seam to be relevant for you.

For example in the `afterModel` hook you can do stuff like:

```
App.PostsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  afterModel: function(posts, transition) {
    if (posts.length === 1) {
      this.transitionTo('post.show', posts[0]);
    }
  }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Funny enough, it turns out that it was a bug with `linkTo` not waiting for promises to finish as can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/machty/5723945#model-and-friends).  Kudos for pointing me to the release notes!